# Bounding the conditional expectation of a normally distributed random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

### The Question

We are given a random variable $X$ on a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$. $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. Given an event $H \in F$, what is the largest possible conditional expectation $E[X\vert H]$. This bound should be given in terms of $P(H)$.

### What I've Done

I reason that, worst case, $H=\{X>\lambda\}$ for some $\lambda$. So I compute
\begin{align*}
E[X\vert H] &\leq \frac{1}{P(\{X>\lambda\})}\int_{\lambda}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx \\
&=\frac{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-\lambda^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\int_{\lambda}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx} \\
&=\frac{\sigma^2e^{\frac{-\lambda^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\int_{\lambda}^\infty e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx}
\end{align*}

From here I'm thinking I could get this in to some manageable function of $\lambda$ or perhaps an approximation, and somehow convert that into a function $P(H)$.

I guess, ultimately it seems to come down to finding $\int_{\lambda}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$ as a function of $P(\{X>\lambda\})$. One observation I have is that the former appears to be the derivative of the latter (up to a constant). Not sure if that helps.

I'm not too knowledgeable about probability, so perhaps there is a much simpler or better approach altogether. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tip: If you want an answer in terms of $P(H)$ , leave $P(H)$ as it is.  Don't substitute an integral for it.

Comment: I think the answer may depend on wether $H$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable or not.

Comment: Let's assume that it is.